# What's the correct way of posting this data asynchronously, and canceling/queuing new requests?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I am attempting to improve the stability of the web dashboard I have created. I have noticed that the main cause of getting into a bad state is when the user moves too quickly and requests get cut short.

For instance, I have the following javascript:

```
//When a resize occurs a lot of handling needs to happen to convert the user's action into
//a visibly-pleasing result. In addition, the server has to be spoken with in order to save the controls.
function OnClientResizing(pane, eventArgs) {
    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    var parameters = new Array();
    parameters.push("Resize");
    parameters.push(pane.get_id());
    parameters.push(eventArgs.get_delta());
    __doPostBack(pane.get_splitter()._uniqueID, parameters);
}
```

This function passes the hard work back to the server, so that it can calculate the appropriate ways to resize the controls on the page during resizes. This takes X seconds. If the user then resizes the page again before X seconds has elapsed -- I enter into a bad state. Either the old request gets cut off prematurely, or the new one runs at the same time. Either way, controls become mishapen on the page.

As such, I would like to queue future resizes, or play around with canceling current requests. I read that the best way to do something like this is to simply set a flag outside the scope of this function. I can do that, but I am not sure how to detect the end of a doPostBack. Am I supposed to change the javascript variable from the server-side somehow in PageRequestManager - EndRequest?

Cheers

Comment: I'm definitely trying to figure out why a server would need to be involved in resizing a layout.  That seems like it needs rethinking.  The layout should be handled entirely client-side.  If you want to save the new layout to the server or send some data off to the server, that's fine, but why make a UI depend upon a server response just to resize itself.  That sounds like a design decision that leads to a poor user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't let your server participate in UI resize algorithms.  Do that entirely client side.  You can send resulting data to the server at any time, but don't make a real-time UI positioning depend upon a server response.  That should be handled client-side with CSS or javascript logic.

Second off, if your code can't handle two ajax calls in flight at the same time, then your options are as follows:

1. Fix your code so it can handle sequential ajax responses in flight at the same time.
2. Cancel/ignore the first ajax response the moment you send a second one so that you ignore the response from the first and wait for the response from the second.
3. Prevent a second ajax request until the first one completes.  I wouldn't suggest queueing them because that's just going to lead to an even worse user experience.

The details of how to do 1, 2 or 3 depend upon how your code works which you have not yet shared.

The easiest is option 3).  That can be done with just a global flag.  Just define a global variable, set it to true when you start an ajax call and clear it when the ajax call completes (in a completion function):

```
var ajaxInFlight = false;  // global declaration

function OnClientResizing(pane, eventArgs) {
    if (ajaxInFlight) return;    // do nothing if ajax call already in flight
    ajaxInFlight = true;
    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    var parameters = new Array();
    parameters.push("Resize");
    parameters.push(pane.get_id());
    parameters.push(eventArgs.get_delta());
    __doPostBack(pane.get_splitter()._uniqueID, parameters);
}

function postBackCompletionHandler(id, parms) {
    ajaxInFlight = false;               // clear global flag, ajax call done
   // ... rest of your function here
}
```

You will also have to make sure that error conditions are handled so that the global flag is reset if the ajax call fails for any reason.

Comment: :) Thank you for your quick response. I am in complete agreement with you regarding the passing off work to the server for UI related tasks, but I inherited a doozy of an issue from Telerik controls which would completely disqualify them from being usable if I did not apply the solution I did. I hope to resolve this when moving to MVC. I will take a look at your suggested solutions and write back when I know more about my options. Thanks again.